# Get specific field using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a specific field from a Dutch bank file: the description of the payment is indicated with `:86:`.

But then the field I need is two lines below.

Example:

```
:86:GIRO··1234567····················ABCD
STREET·99····················CITY
LB1234NL·························DATE
```

I would like to get the reference "LB1234NL" as a result.

I'm almost there, but just not quite:

```
(?<=:86:.{1,65}\r\n)(.*\r\n){2}
```

This gives me the second and third line.
But then I'm stuck.

Comment: consider tagging your question with the language/tool you are using..regex implementation differs across languages/tools

Comment: Is it a clieop3 file? I think there are plenty of parsers for those files. What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extracts it as first group:

```
(?<=:86:.*\n.*\n)\w+
```

Please note you didn't specify a language and OS. This is working in Linux with Perl.

Comment: I am using it to get bank statements into SAP (using a SAP tool), and I am trying to convert the reference to the field on the 3rd line. For that I must use a regex "formula" and then the tool will put the value in the field I want. Your formula (:86:.*\n.*\n(\w+)\.*) almost works, because when I test in Expresso (in which you can test regex), I see two line: the full detail and then the reference I need in the first group. Unfortunately, the SAP tool does not pick that up and just picks up the "main" line. Is there a way, I can have a formula that just get the refence?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about SAP or its regexes. What do you mean by "main line"?

Comment: This is wat expresso gives me (see image: main line and then the field I need). But I don't know enough (read: first time I have to use it) to only keep that info as I only have 1 field to enter my regex "formula". http://tinypic.com/r/2v0xrgp/5

Comment: I don't understand anything you told me in this last comment. I see in the image it is extracting the field you want, so what's the problem?

Comment: In the picture you see 2 lines: one main line (starting with :86:) and a sub-line (starting with 1:). The SAP tool doesn't care about the second line, but only looks at the first one. When I use (?<=:86:.{1,65}\r\n)(.*\r\n), I get the same result twice (STREET·99····················CITY), but that's not the one I need ...

Comment: You can try with `(?<=:86:.*\n.*\n)\w+` but I cannot test this because variable length lookbehinds are not implemented in Perl 5.14. Also most likely not implemented in SAP as well.

Comment: What would the expression be if I would take the following approach: when the text starts with :86:, then look further and give me the string that starts with "LB" and ends with "NL"?

Comment: So variable length lookbehinds are implemented in SAP. Nice to know. About your new question if the previous regex worked fine, this should be what you're asking `(?<=:86:.*\n.*\n)LB\w+NL`

Answer (score 0):

Using perl you can extract that value:

```
perl -0pe 's/:86:(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n){2}([A-Z0-9]+)([^\r\n]*\r?\n)*/\1/' file
```

Comment: @m0skit0: Try your posted regex with perl command and you would know :P

Comment: Oh I see, you're right. But who asked for a Perl command one-liner? :)

Comment: @m0skit0: Just the `regex` tag can never tell on what platform OP wants the answer :P